# Error while installing MTconnect agent on Debian Linux

Tags: debian, iot, mtconnect

```
apt install libxml2 libxml2-dev cmake git build-essential libcppunit-dev

git clone https://github.com/mtconnect/cppagent.git

cd cppagent

cmake .
```

when running cmake . Im getting this error

```
INFO Shared build: OFF
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  agent_lib/CMakeLists.txt:293 (find_package)
```

Any Suggestions??